# print the count and the line after search based on pattern

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, scripting, uniq

I have lines like this in multiple log files

FILE 1:

```
Line 203:Caused by :arithmatic overflow exception

Line 204:at com.abc.java
```

FILE 2:

```
Line 105:Caused by : ???String out of bound exception

Line 206 :at com.def.java
```

There are many files which contain the above pattern.how to do I count the occurances of combination of line no 203 + line no 204 in all those files

Comment: There are several "patterns" in your example, please [edit] your question to tell us what you mean by "the above pattern". Also add what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious way would be:

```
grep -l 'Line 203:' * | xargs grep 'Line 204:' | wc -l
```